# Replace Second Toolbar on Fragment Xamarin Android

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to make an android app with two toolbar in activity. I make two toolbar so I can add action to each fragment activity. But I got trouble.

Well, I can replace the top toolbar when the other fragment showing off with this code:

```
 public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        //SearchMenu
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.nav_search, menu);
        var searchItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
        var provider = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(searchItem);
        mSearchView = provider.JavaCast<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView>();
        mSearchView.QueryTextSubmit += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "You searched: " + args.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };
    }
```

And it works perfectly. And I tried add option menu on second toolbar and ended like this:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        //SearchMenu
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.nav_search, menu);
        var searchItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
        var provider = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(searchItem);
        mSearchView = provider.JavaCast<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView>();
        mSearchView.QueryTextSubmit += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "You searched: " + args.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        //ActionMenu
        var mBottomToolbar = this.Activity.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.secondToolbar);
        mBottomToolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.nav_manageLocation);
        mBottomToolbar.MenuItemClick += (sender, e) =>
        {

            switch (e.Item.ToString())
            {
                case "Add":
                    ReplaceFragment(new LocationAddFragment(), "addlocation");
                    break;
            }

            base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        };
    }
```

Well the `nav_manageLocation` added to second toolbar. But It wont replace the old second toolbar. So now I got two menu in the second toolbar the old and the new one.

Is there a way so I only can show only the new menu on second toolbar?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiosoOk5tzcAhXPfX0KHRADCooQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2015%2F09%2Fandroid-material-design-working-with-tabs%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Oq5ghmtDMeE5bydYVkvxi&ust=1533795135320229

Comment: Yea like that.. I got the tabbed page but I want the fixed second toolbar just like instagram. Well this is because of my conventional lecturer :(

Comment: That's not two toolbars!! Instagram has but one toolbar the other part is a tabbed page and when you scroll they hide the toolbar something like this https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hide+toolbar+on+scrolling+android&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN776IN776&oq=hide+toolbar+on+page+scroll+andro&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.13166j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Well thanks, I put the tabbed bar on the bottom. Thanks mate

Comment: Sure man no problem